# MySQL query to get all items that do not belong to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem that I haven't been able to resolve for some hours.

I have 3 tables:

- **`Process`**

  ```
  +----+----------+----------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+
  | id |   name   |  description   | active | responsible | informByEmail | informBySms | remarks | icon |
  +----+----------+----------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+
  |  4 | Process1 | TestDecriptino |      1 |           0 |             0 |           0 | 0       | NULL |
  |  5 | Process2 | test           |      0 |           0 |             0 |           0 | test    | NULL |
  |  6 | Process3 | 12322          |      1 |           0 |             0 |           0 | 12322   | NULL |
  |  7 | Process4 | 222222222222   |      0 |           0 |             0 |           0 | 2222222 | NULL |
  |  9 | Process5 | sgdasad        |      1 |           0 |             1 |           0 | dhds    | NULL |
  +----+----------+----------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+
  ```
- **`Systems`**

  ```
  +----+---------+-------------+--------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+
  | id |  name   | description | active | responsibleUserId | informByEmail | informBySms | remarks | icon |
  +----+---------+-------------+--------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+
  |  2 | Sistem1 | fdjgf       |      1 |                 1 |             1 |           1 | 0       | NULL |
  |  6 | Sistem2 | koam        |      0 |                 3 |             1 |           0 | SADGS   | NULL |
  +----+---------+-------------+--------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+
  ```
- **`Process_Systems`**

  ```
  +----+-----------+----------+--------+---------+
  | id | processId | systemId | active | remarks |
  +----+-----------+----------+--------+---------+
  |  4 |         4 |        2 |      1 | aa      |
  |  8 |         7 |        2 |      1 | aa      |
  | 11 |         9 |        2 |      1 | aa      |
  | 15 |         4 |        6 |      0 | aa      |
  +----+-----------+----------+--------+---------+
  ```

I have a method to which `processID` is a parameter and must somehow filter all `Process_Systems` by that ID and then get `Systems` which do not belong to the `Process_Systems` table.

Answer (score 2):

- One way would be to use a [`NOT IN` subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html):

  ```
  SELECT   *
  FROM     Systems
  WHERE    id NOT IN (
             SELECT systemid
             FROM   Process_Systems
             WHERE  processId = ?
           );
  ```
- Another would be to use a [`NOT EXISTS` subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

  ```
  SELECT   *
  FROM     Systems
  WHERE    NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT *
             FROM   Process_Systems
             WHERE  systemId = Systems.id
                AND processId = ?
           );
  ```
- A third way would be to use an [outer join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

  ```
  SELECT   Systems.*
  FROM     Systems LEFT JOIN Process_Systems ps
        ON ps.systemId = Systems.id
       AND ps.processId = ?
  WHERE    ps.systemId IS NULL;
  ```

See them on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53480/1).

For an analysis of the respective performance differences, see @Quassnoi's blog articles:

- [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)
- [LEFT JOIN / IS NULL vs. NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS: nullable columns](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)